# Count formula based of content in other cell 30 page workbook

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula

I am working on a 30 page workbook. I am trying to get a count of how many time content is put in to a cell and then put that count in a another cell. I working with parking and overflow of lots so if the lot overflow I am trying to track how many times based of the cell that is the time of the overflow starts and put the number of time on the average page of the workbook.

Comment: I believe you'll need a `Worksheet_Change()` event on that sheet, where you track if the specific cell is changed.  What have you tried?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet because I really don't know what type of formula to use. I have never heard of worksheet_change () formula. I am using Excel 2010 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
=COUNTA(Sheet1:Sheet30!A1)
```

where, `A1` is the cell you are trying to get a count of and `Sheet1:Sheet30` refer to all sheets from `Sheet1` to `Sheet30`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get a count of how many time content is put in to a cell and then put that count in a another cell.

Assuming the counting takes place in B1, then in say D1 to *put that count in a another cell*:

```
=B1
```

To *count how many times content is put into a cell* (for example into A1) in cell B1, in B1:

```
=IF(A1<>"",B1+1)
```

To get the above to work, in FILE > Options > Formulas > Calculation options check *Enable iterative calculation* and set Maximum Iterations to `1`.

Comment: ok so how would would I get it to count for content putin to cell A1 on all 30 pages, my pages are in order 1-31 because this is workbook we put data in daily and have a average sheet at the end that we then take at the end of the month and put in to a year report.